# Relation between the differential of a vector field and the covariant derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a Riemannian manifold and let $X:\mathcal{M} \rightarrow \mathcal{T}\mathcal{M}$ be a smooth vector field, i.e., $X(p) \in \mathcal{T}_p\mathcal{M}$ $\forall p \in \mathcal{M}$. Is it true that the covariant derivative along a curve $\gamma$ is the same thing as the differential of $X$ applied to the tangent vector along $\gamma$? In other words, does the following hold:
\begin{equation}
\frac{D X}{dt} |_{t=t_p} = D_p X [\gamma'],
\end{equation}

where $\gamma'$ is the tangent vector along $\gamma$ at $\gamma(t_p) = p$.

Sofar I've tried to show that the differential is the Levi-Civita connection. Showing that it defines a connection, seems to work by using the chain rule. For this let $f \in C^\infty(\mathcal{M})$. Then $f(p)Y(p)$ is well defined and we have
\begin{align}
  D_p f Y [X] &= (D_v (\cdot)Z, \,  D_Z v(\cdot) )_{(f(p),Y(p))} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
 D_p f(\cdot) \\
 D_p Y(\cdot)
 \end{pmatrix} [X] \\
 & = (Z, \,   v)_{(f(p),Y(p))} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
 D_p f(\cdot) \\
 D_p Y(\cdot)
 \end{pmatrix} [X] = (Y(p), \,   f(p)) \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
 D_p f(\cdot) \\
 D_p Y(\cdot)
 \end{pmatrix} [X]\\
 & = Y(p) D_p f [X] + f(p) D_p Y [X] = (Xf)_p Y(p) + f(p)D_p Y[X] 
\end{align}
So indeed, this defines a connection.

However, I get stuck when trying to show symmetry and metric compatibility.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: If $X:M\to TM$ is a vector field then $DX$ is a map $TM\to T(TM)$, whence $DX[\gamma']$ is an element of $T_{X_p}(T_pM)$ while $\nabla_{\gamma'}X$ is an element of $T_pM$. You need to further massage your derivative to compare the two. But even if you have done that note that the Levi Civita connection depends on the metric, but the derivative has no connection at all to the metric. So a general equality is completely out of the question.

Comment: The first points shouldn't be much of a problem since you can identify $\mathcal{T}_{X_p}(\mathcal{T}_p\mathcal{M})$ with $\mathcal{T}_p\mathcal{M}$. However, if your second claim is true, than that could indeed give trouble.

Comment: @WillemDiepeveen This is interesting... Note that $T_pM$ and $TM$ are different manifolds. You can indeed identify $T_{X_p}(T_pM)$ with $T_p M$ since $T_pM$ is a vector space, but here you are dealing with $T_{X_p}(TM)$ or more precisely $T_{(p,X_p)}(TM)$. This will tell you why the statement you are trying to prove is not true (I think).

Comment: Since it now seems more and more reasonable that equality does not hold, is there maybe some other relation between the two? Is there a way you can approximate the one with the other up to some higher order error term then?